# Codeigniter showing error when I try to resubmit form with csrf_protection set to true

Tags: codeigniter, csrf-protection

My CI website has csrf protection.

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
```

So, when I resubmit form by refresh I am getting the following error.

> The action you have requested is not allowed

**Instead of showing this message, I want it to return to last page.**

So, I try to override **csrf_show_error()** method by extending the **CI_Security** file.

This is my class located in *application/core/My_Security.php*

```
class MY_Security extends CI_Security {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('user_agent');
    }

    public function csrf_show_error()
    {
        // show_error('The action you have requested is not allowed.');  // default code

        // force page "refresh" - redirect back to itself 
        // a page refresh restores the CSRF cookie      
        if ($this->agent->is_referral())
        {
            redirect(site_url());

        } else {            
            redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);         
        }        
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error

> Call to a member function library() on a non-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Insted of changing the core classes, I extended the MY_Securtiy class in core folder of application. and redirecting to past page.***

**File Location:** application\core\MY_Security.php

```
class MY_Security extends CI_Security {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();      
    }

    public function csrf_show_error()
    {
        header('Location: ' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), TRUE, 200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your solution, but it seems better with a return code 302 by changing the request type of the new request to GET, regardless of the type employed in the original request (e.g. POST). The next refresh will not ask any question.